# Jackson Databind complaining about unused enum

Tags: spring-boot, jackson-databind

I have a project which is split in small (kind of micro-) services and libraries:

- de.kreth.data (library for data classes)
- de.kreth.vaadincomponents (ui library)
- de.kreth.model (Rest Service, Spring Boot MVC)
- de.kreth.personedit (Vaadin UI Frontend/ RestClient)

The problem is caused in Jackson databind within these classes:

```java
package de.kreth.data;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * The persistent class for the person database table.
 */
public class Person extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
  private LocalDate birth;
  private String prename;
  private String surname;
  private Integer gender;
  private List<GroupDef> groups;
  public LocalDate getBirth() {
    return birth;
  }

  [some getter/setter]

  public void setGender(Integer gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
  }
  
  public Integer getGender() {
    return gender;
  }
  
  public boolean isMember(GroupDef group) {
    return groups != null && groups.contains(group);
  }
}
```

```java
package de.kreth.data;

public enum Gender {
  MALE(1), FEMALE(2);
  private final int id;
  
  private Gender(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  
  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }
  
  public static Gender valueOf(Integer id) {
    if (id != null) {
      return valueOf(id.intValue());
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
  
  public static Gender valueOf(int id) {
    for (Gender g : values()) {
      if (g.id == id) {
        return g;
      }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Gender for id=" + id + " defined.");
  }
}
```

And this is the exception thrown:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Input mismatch reading Enum `de.kreth.clubhelper.data.Gender`: properties-based `@JsonCreator` ([method de.kreth.clubhelper.data.Gender#valueOf(1 params)]) expects JSON Object (JsonToken.START_OBJECT), got JsonToken.VALUE_NUMBER_INT; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Input mismatch reading Enum `de.kreth.clubhelper.data.Gender`: properties-based `@JsonCreator` ([method de.kreth.clubhelper.data.Gender#valueOf(1 params)]) expects JSON Object (JsonToken.START_OBJECT), got JsonToken.VALUE_NUMBER_INT
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 156] (through reference chain: java.lang.Object[][0]->de.kreth.clubhelper.data.Person["gender"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:284) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:250) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:105) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 170 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Input mismatch reading Enum `de.kreth.clubhelper.data.Gender`: properties-based `@JsonCreator` ([method de.kreth.clubhelper.data.Gender#valueOf(1 params)]) expects JSON Object (JsonToken.START_OBJECT), got JsonToken.VALUE_NUMBER_INT
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 156] (through reference chain: java.lang.Object[][0]->de.kreth.clubhelper.data.Person["gender"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1468) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.FactoryBasedEnumDeserializer.deserialize(FactoryBasedEnumDeserializer.java:120) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:371) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:164) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:195) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:21) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4524) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3519) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:273) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 172 common frames omitted
```

As you can see, Person does not contain the enum Gender anymore. As I hat problems to get this working, I removed the relation. Unfortunately the error remains.

I checked, that I really use the correct code by setting a unique version to all projects, which is checked out.

I checked, that really all projects are referencing the correct git repo, by this version number.

I checked, that the checkout code is correct.

I checked, that all projects reference the correct libraries.

Why is jackson complaining about Enum `de.kreth.clubhelper.data.Gender` at de.kreth.clubhelper.data.Person["gender"]?

Comment: `Person` and `Gender` are located in two different projects?

Comment: No, they are in the same project and same package. There was a typo in the code. I removed the clubhelper part inconsistantly. Sorry.